# Slow Django Model Formset Rendering

Tags: python, html, django, inline-formset, django-debug-toolbar

I have a Django Model Formset that is rendered with a crispy-forms in a custom table inline formset template. The formset is a list of alerts with entities, logic, and comments. Entity and logic are populated in each form, and the user writes a comment prior to submitting the form.

The formset currently has 140 forms (i.e. 140 records in the Alert model), and it will need to handle more than that number. It takes 4-5 minutes for `alerts.html` to render. I can use Django-based pagination to limit the queryset and reduce rendering time, but this precludes me from using something like jQuery datatables to paginate and quickly add JS functionality.

I used `django-debug-toolbar` to review. The queries are definitely funky and duplicated per form (i.e. the query grabbing entity information is duplicated for each form and also includes duplicate `where` statements). However, it only takes 3-4 seconds for the queries to run, so the problem must be elsewhere. I used Chrom dev tools to record the performance, and the `Waiting (TTFB)` time is the cause of the performance issue. I understand that this involves server-side processing, which leads me to believe it is a Django issue.

Why is the render taking so long? Is there anything in my code below that could be optimized? I know caching is an option, but I believe this mostly affects query performance which doesn't appear to be the driving issue. Is there any other piece of `django-debug-toolbar` that might shed more light on timing, outside of just the queries?

**EDIT:** Based on the comments, I determined the `include` tags in the `table_inline_formset.html` template are causing the issue because they are rendering hundreds of the same templates. I created another question here to address this problem: [Crispy-Forms Include Tag Causing Many Duplicate Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47559245/crispy-forms-include-tag-causing-many-duplicate-templates).

models.py:

```
class Logic(models.Model):
    logic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.logic

class Entity(models.Model):
    entity = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12)
    entityType = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    entityDescription = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s - %s' % (self.entity, self.entityType, self.entityDescription)

class Alert(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='entity')
    logic = models.ForeignKey(Logic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='logic')
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.entity
```

forms.py:

```
AlertFormSet = modelformset_factory(Alert, extra=1, exclude=(), form=AlertForm)

class AlertFormsetHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AlertFormsetHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.template = 'alerts/table_inline_formset.html'
        self.add_input(Submit("submit", "Submit"))
        self.layout = Layout(
            Field('entity', css_class="input"),
            Field('logic', css_class="input"),
            Field('comment', css_class="input")
        )
```

views.py:

```
    def alerts(request):
        newAlerts = Alert.objects.filter(disposition='')
        formset = AlertFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=newAlerts)
        helper = AlertFormsetHelper()
        context = {'formset':formset, 'helper':helper}
        if request.method == 'POST':
            for form in formset:
                if form.is_valid():
                    if form.has_changed():
                        if form.is_valid():
                            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/alerts')
        return render(request, 'alerts/alerts.html', context)
```

table_inline_formset.html:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load crispy_forms_utils %}
{% load crispy_forms_field %}
{% specialspaceless %}
{% if formset_tag %}
<form {{ flat_attrs|safe }} method="{{ form_method }}" {% if formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
{% endif %}
    {% if formset_method|lower == 'post' and not disable_csrf %}
        {% csrf_token %}
    {% endif %}
    <div>
        {{ formset.management_form|crispy }}
    </div>
      <div class='table-responsive'>
    <table{% if form_id %} id="{{ form_id }}_table"{% endif%} class="table table-hover table-sm" id='dispositionTable'>
        <thead>
            {% if formset.readonly and not formset.queryset.exists %}
            {% else %}
                <tr>
                    {% for field in formset.forms.0 %}
                        {% if field.label and not field|is_checkbox and not field.is_hidden %}
                            <th for="{{ field.auto_id }}" class="form-control-label {% if field.field.required %}requiredField{% endif %}">
                                {{ field.label|safe }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="asteriskField">*</span>{% endif %}
                            </th>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for form in formset %}
                {% if form_show_errors and not form.is_extra %}
                    {% include "bootstrap4/errors.html" %}
                {% endif %}
                <tr>
                    {% for field in form %}
                        {% include 'bootstrap4/field.html' with tag="td" form_show_labels=False %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% include "bootstrap4/inputs.html" %}
{% if formset_tag %}</form>{% endif %}
{% endspecialspaceless %}
```

alerts.html:

```
{% crispy formset helper %}
```

Comment: This isn't primarily Django issue. The problem is the amount of HTML and browsers have difficulties swallowing it.

Comment: can you please elaborate? is this really a lot of html? i have a similar page that is a search of already commented alerts, and it loads extremely quickly, despite having more JavaScript. granted, it doesn't have the `table_inline_formset.html` template.

Comment: You can save 2 db queries per form by using `newAlerts = Alert.objects.filter(disposition='').select_related('entity', 'logic')`. Otherwise these related objects have to be fetched from the db for every form in the set.

Comment: I don't know how much html is it in your case, but I was working on a project where I had similar situation with about 200 - 250 forms and it was dead slow. I rendered html to log and it was quick, but browsers just couldn't swallow it in reasonable time. Anyway, I moved away from formset and went with standard edit button and a couple rows of formset for new entries.

Comment: @schwobaseggl thanks - i'll add that, although the queries are not taking that long according to django-debug-toolbar. looks like Waiting (TTFB) (shown in Chrome dev tools) is the driver of the issue. i understand this is related to server-side performance, which makes me think it's a django issue

Comment: @Borut do you have a link to any resources that might explain that approach a little more?

Comment: What can also slow you down is many `include` that render separately. I guess you have a couple 100s. Try replacing the `include` tags in all the for loops by the partials template's html directly.

Comment: the `include` tags in `table_inline_formset.html`? so change `{% include "bootstrap4/errors.html" %}` to what?

Comment: @schwobaseggl adding `select_related` didn't move the needle - same number of queries

Comment: @schwobaseggl i believe you're right about the include - django-debug-toolbar is showing 300+ templates rendered with the bootstrap4/field.html and bootstrap4/errors.html rendering for each field in each form. what should i change those to?

Comment: Insert the html from the included templates directly into your loops instead of using the tag. If these are from third-party apps, look for them them in your site-packages or directly on github.

Comment: @schwobaseggl ah, so take the html from the crispy-forms templates and insert it in the loops. what about the one with extra statements like `with tag="td"`?

Comment: i definitely need to include `with tag='td'` somehow. also, the templates replacing `include` have their own `include` statements (i.e. nested templates). should i just build the entire crispy-forms template deck into one template?

Comment: Yup, you can just insert that value wherever tag is used, but at this point you should wonder if you really need that many forms in one page or if you should use some form of pagination. If this is just an administrative backend, don't worry about performance too much. If actual customers come to this page, you should question the design.

Comment: i am planning on using pagination with jQuery datatables to match the rest of my site...rather than using Django's built-in pagination. this requires the full queryset, however. regardless, pagination doesn't fix the base issue that too many templates are rendering. that problem exists whether there are two forms or 100.

Comment: @CameronTaylor, geez, I didn't see it takes 4-5 minutes to render. That's definitely not slow browser rendering issue. I thought it's 4-5 seconds.

Comment: @Borut yeah...it was terrible. Decided to stop using crispy-forms and just manually render the formset to a table. That got it down to 3 seconds.

Comment: @CameronTaylor , I'm having a similar problem, is it the crispy forms?

Comment: @durdenk kind of, yes. essentially all the `include` tags created a hierarchy of `include` in the crispy forms templates and it was loading a massive amount of files. i switched to just manually rendering the table and feeding it into a jQuery datatable. in my opinion, it's much cleaner and simpler.