# Crispy-Forms Include Tag Causing Many Duplicate Templates

Tags: python, html, django, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django site that uses the below template to render a crispy-forms model formset. Using `django-debug-toolbar`, I gathered that the `include` tags are rendering the bootstrap4 templates many, many times. I think this is what is killing my performance (i.e. 3-4 minutes to load an inline formset with 100 forms in it)

How should I replace the `include` tags to avoid the duplicate rendering? Should I use extend somehow?

I can replace the `include` tags with the actual html from the bootstrap4 crispy-forms templates, but those templates have nested templates as well. That creates an exercising of building a master crispy-forms template that includes everything...which seems like the wrong way to go about this. In addition, I tried replace the `bootstrap4/field.html` include tag with the actual html, and `field.html` was still duplicated, and the data lost it's table structure because of the loss of `with tag='td'`.

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load crispy_forms_utils %}
{% load crispy_forms_field %}
{% specialspaceless %}
{% if formset_tag %}
<form {{ flat_attrs|safe }} method="{{ form_method }}" {% if formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
{% endif %}
    {% if formset_method|lower == 'post' and not disable_csrf %}
        {% csrf_token %}
    {% endif %}
    <div>
        {{ formset.management_form|crispy }}
    </div>
      <div class='table-responsive'>
    <table{% if form_id %} id="{{ form_id }}_table"{% endif%} class="table table-hover table-sm" id='dispositionTable'>
        <thead>
            {% if formset.readonly and not formset.queryset.exists %}
            {% else %}
                <tr>
                    {% for field in formset.forms.0 %}
                        {% if field.label and not field|is_checkbox and not field.is_hidden %}
                            <th for="{{ field.auto_id }}" class="form-control-label {% if field.field.required %}requiredField{% endif %}">
                                {{ field.label|safe }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="asteriskField">*</span>{% endif %}
                            </th>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for form in formset %}
                {% if form_show_errors and not form.is_extra %}
                    {% include "bootstrap4/errors.html" %}
                {% endif %}
                <tr>
                    {% for field in form %}
                        {% include 'bootstrap4/field.html' with tag="td" form_show_labels=False %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% include "bootstrap4/inputs.html" %}
{% if formset_tag %}</form>{% endif %}
{% endspecialspaceless %}
```